# JQuery DOM. $.html

Tags: jquery, html, dom

```
// Event onClick for links
$(window).load(function() {

    $("a[href=#sign-in]").click(function(){
        $.post("/index.php/start_ctrl/signin", function(data){
            $("body>div.row").html(data);
        })
    })
    $("a[href=#profile]").click(function(){
        $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/profile", function(data){
            $("body>div.row").html(data);
        })
    })
    $("a[href=#editInfo]").click(function(){
        $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/editinfo", function(data){
            $("div.profilepanel").html(data);
        })
    })

});

//Link at the topbar

    <a href="#profile">Profile</a>


//When I have clicked on link at the topbar, it's triggered event $("a[href=#profile]").click
```

And `div.row` accept this data:

```
<div class="row">
   <li><a href="#editInfo">Change information</a></li>
</div>
```

This link have jquery event too... `$("a[href=#editInfo]").click`

But event not triggered!

If this link placed where browser loads straight (**without DOM**), then this link works.
And link, which appended trough DOM, doesn't work :(

How I can fix it?

P.S Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood the `#editInfo` link does not exits when the page is loaded, it is loaded when the `#profile` is clicked. That means `editInfo` is an dynamic element so you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$(document).on('click', "a[href=#editInfo]", function () {
    $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/editinfo", function (data) {
        $("div.profilepanel").html(data);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

add '' to the search attribute value.
try this:

```
$("a[href='#sign-in']").click(function(){
    $.post("/index.php/start_ctrl/signin", function(data){
        $("body>div.row").html(data);
    })
})
$("a[href='#profile']").click(function(){
    $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/profile", function(data){
        $("body>div.row").html(data);
    })
})
$("a[href='#editInfo']").click(function(){
    $.post("/index.php/profile_ctrl/editinfo", function(data){
        $("div.profilepanel").html(data);
    })
})
```

Comment: $("a[href='#editInfo']").click(function(){ still, doesn't work :(